# How to get data from collection within collection in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: data structure]

I am making a quiz application with React. There is a collection of questions in my category collection. I can access categories. How can I access this collection of questions? What should I add to my code?

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const catRef = collection(db, "categories");

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(catRef);
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    //const questionRef = collection(db, `categories/${doc.id}/questions`);
     
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `collection(db, 'categories/${categoryId}/questions');` approach is correct if you are trying to get questions of a specific category.

If you are trying to fetch questions from all categories then you can use a [`collectionGroup()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) query instead:

```
import { collectionGroup, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";  

const questions = query(collectionGroup(db, 'questions'));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(museums);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I can reach all the questions with this, but I could not reach the question in the specific collection. So I couldn't fully use the approach you approved. 
`const questionRef = collection(db, `categories/${doc.id}/questions`);` How and where exactly should I use this?